# Does $\sup_{|u|\le r} f(u)\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$f(u) = 1+2u^2.$$
My question is: for any $r>0$, does $$\sup_{|u|\le r} f(u)\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})?$$

In my opinion the answer is yes, since when $|u|\le r$, thus $f(u)\le 1+r^2<+\infty$, but has been subject of discussion in my calculus class.
Could anyone please tell me if my reasoning hold true?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $r>0$, the quantity $\sup\limits_{|u|\leq r}f(u)=1+2r^2$ is a real number, so it cannot belong to $L^{\infty}(\Bbb{R})$. So as written your question is very vague.

- If you're talking about fixing an $r>0$ and considering the constant function $x\mapsto \sup\limits_{|u|\leq r}f(u)$ defined on $\Bbb{R}$, then of course it belongs to $L^{\infty}(\Bbb{R})$.
- On the other hand if you're talking about the function $g(r):=\sup\limits_{|u|\leq r}f(u)=1+2r^2$ (if $r>0$) and for $r\leq 0$ defined in whatever way you like, then no the function $g$ is unbounded so it does not lie in $L^{\infty}(\Bbb{R})$.

Comment: It is the first one case. Thank you for your answer.